# Watson Assistant Context Variable Counter 2021

Tags: variables, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I know this has been asked multiple times in the past but the code seems not to work for me and I think Watson interfaces changed a lot since 2017 :(

I want to add a counter to a multiple conditioned responses node. After the 3rd time asking the same question the bot should jump to another node.

At welcome I created a context Variable: `counter` with value: `0`

[image: Screenshot 1]

At the multiple conditioned responses node I set a context variable for each answer. Variable: `counter` Value: `"<? $counter + 1 ?>"`

[image: Screenshot 2]

But instead of updating the value number of `counter` to `1` it updates the value to `"['counter'] + 1"` The computation doesn't work. So how can I solve this?

[image: Screenshot 3]

If the computation would work, I would add another conditioned response and let Watson check for: `$counter > 3` and if that true it would jump to another node.

Would be very thankful for any advise :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to handle the computations by [editing the dialog node in JSON](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-runtime-context#dialog-runtime-context-var-json). You probably know this, but else see this section on [how to access objects in Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language). Make sure the assignment is performed in the **context** section.

Your code should work to increase the counter by one:

```
<? $counter + 1 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @data_henrik !